# Does XML 1.0 support LINUX environment variables

Tags: xml, linux, environment-variables

Can is there a standard to mark LINUX variables in  XML 1.0?
For example, something similar to Ruby code ENV["PWD"].
I could not find any reference, but I could have missed something.
Thanks

Comment: XML isn't a programming language. You can't write programs in XML, it's just for storing data.

Comment: Many thanks! That is what I have thought, but you definitely phrased it better!